# SharePoint 2010 - compound Fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, field, content-type

Hi
I have a SharePoint (2010) list for contacts (people).

Among the fields, I have a 'roles' column, (choice) as a list of checkboxes, so a user can have 0, one, or many roles.

I now need to have a date-start and date-end associated to each role.

What I want is a custom (field??) that combines 'role', 'date-start' and 'date-end', and have that new combined field added as a column to my contacts list as a  multiple-choice.

Is this possible/recommended?

... or should this be separate, related lists?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say create a separate list to store the roles, and use a lookup column to link the two lists together.

I don't think you can have more than one type of data stored in a column (unless you concatenate the data into a string and store it in a text field)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I guess it will also require some sharepoint designer work to bring it all toghter into the details/edit views as well.